# porting Visual Studio asm to g++ basic asm

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I have the following simple but frustrating problem: I´m using g++ compiler, but the code i´m using as example is written for use with Visual Studio. Usually not a problem, but their inline assemblers work differently, so the code needs to be changed.

The snipped in question is as follows:

```
float someotherfuncname(inputvar)
{
    //For example purposes. Can be arbitrary amount of math.
    return 1;
}

void __declspec(naked)funcname(void)
{
    __asm
    {   
        push    ecx
        call    someotherfuncname
        pop     ecx
        retn
    }
}
```

I have no experience on this topic, basically i´m meticulously copying an arcane formula written by a more experienced coder in the hopes of reproducing the results (with success on other parts, but this one got me).

The main issues, as far as i´ve identified them are:

-g++ asm does not have "retn".

-"call" uses stuff from the surrounding c++ program. g++ asm can´t easily use c++ stuff without extendend asm. The __declspec(naked) prevents me from using extended asm.

-I have no idea what "retn" does so i can´t fake it with equivalent code.

EDIT: I´m using Windows.

The purpose is to build a .dll to be used by OBSE for TES Oblivion. I´m building it with g++ (probably MinGW).

A minimal sketch of a (not) working code would be: In the .h file (not a problem, just for completeness):

```
#ifndef MSK_B
#define MSK_B

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef DLL_KOMP
#define SPECK __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SPECK __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

bool SPECK OBSEPlugin_Query(const OBSEInterface * obse, PluginInfo * info);

bool SPECK OBSEPlugin_Load(const OBSEInterface * obse);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // MMC_B_H
```

In the .cpp file: Note, OBSEInterface and PluginInfo aren´t defined here, but they aren´t needed (only some skeleton definition to make the compiler happy so i left them out).

```
include "[name of the .h file]"
include <fstream>
include "Windows.h"

typedef unsigned long UInt32

void SafeWrite8(UInt32 addr, UInt32 data)
{
    UInt32  oldProtect;

    VirtualProtect((void *)addr, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    *((UInt8 *)addr) = data;
    VirtualProtect((void *)addr, 4, oldProtect, &oldProtect);
}

void SafeWrite32(UInt32 addr, UInt32 data)
{
    UInt32  oldProtect;

    VirtualProtect((void *)addr, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    *((UInt32 *)addr) = data;
    VirtualProtect((void *)addr, 4, oldProtect, &oldProtect);
}

void WriteRelPaddedCall(UInt32 strtAddr, UInt32 retnAddr, UInt32 callbackAddr)
{
    for (UInt32 i = strtAddr; i < retnAddr; i++) SafeWrite8(i,0x90);
    WriteRelCall(strtAddr,callbackAddr);
}

extern "C" {
bool SPECK OBSEPlugin_Query(const OBSEInterface * obse, PluginInfo * info)
{
    return true;
}

bool SPECK OBSEPlugin_Load(const OBSEInterface * obse)
{
    UInt32 RuesDispAddrH = 0x005AB365;
    UInt32 RuesDispAddrR = 0x005AB36D;
    //RuestungECX is the function i posted above.
    //This line (as implemented here) causes the game to crash when loading a game (or starting a new game).
    WriteRelPaddedCall(RuesDispAddrH, RuesDispAddrR, (UInt32) &RuestungECX);
    return true;
}
};
```

Comment: *g++ asm does not have "call"* - Yes it does, it's a valid x86 mnemonic.    Why do you think it doesn't? ([mcve] of your g++ attemp). An `__attribute__((naked))` function is probably the only time it's a good idea to use it inside an statement, so this code should port easily. (And BTW, `retn` is just normal `ret` (near as opposed to far).  But really it would be best if you eliminated the inline asm entirely and used pure C, instead of some old 32-bit stack-args calling convention that's definitely going to misalign the stack by 16 so it's not portable to Linux even if you keep 32-bit mode

Comment: Are you using g++ for Windows (Like MinGW, TDM)? Other seem to suggest you are porting to Linux, although I don't see anything that says you are moving off the Windows platform.

Comment: I´m trying to write a plugin for OBSE (for TES Oblivion). I have no idea about that stuff, i´m basically trying to copy the code for another plugin that works. If I knew what the function needs to do I might be able to reproduce it in pure C, but well, i don´t.

Comment: Thanks for the note that "call" exists and that there is at least "ret". I tried to update the post to be more complete.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Not maintaining stack alignment was something I noticed, but then I remembered that only Linux's 32-bit ABI requires 16-byte stack alignment so I suggested it as a possible advantage.  If you're going to rework some old code, might as well aim to make it more portable if you have to re-engineer something anyway.

Comment: *g++ asm can´t easily use c++ stuff without extendend asm* - what, does MSVC turn that `call someotherfuncname` into a call to a name-mangled version of that function, if only one declaration (not overloaded) is visible?  G++ won't do that, but nothing is stopping you from calling C++ functions you define with `extern "C"`.  (You might possibly need `__attribute__((used))` if the only caller is from asm where the compiler can't see it, and the function is `static` or something.  This is one reason why machine function calls from inline asm sucks and you should try to just use C++)

Comment: g++ --version   output: g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0

Comment: I don't know anything about the code but I assume the use of ECX here is to massage a CDECL call to a THISCALL calling convention. Is the `funcname` you are actually showing here the function you are actually trying to convert?

Comment: Actually more like a THISCALL to CECL (not the other way around) but `somefunc` doesn't seem to be a complete function.

Comment: BTW, `clang -fasm-blocks` can compile that asm block, including handling the name-mangling for `call somefunc` automagically: https://godbolt.org/z/vzzov5.  Probably clang-cl could compile it unmodified.  Of course a non-inlineable function call sucks for efficiency, probably best to just declare it as `__attribute__((cdecl))` or whatever so everything knows how to call it directly instead of inefficiently going through this wrapper.

Comment: @peter-cordes ow sorry. I didn't read your comment. You write it before.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP: That's fine, maybe I should have posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it fits you, but you can compile msvc stile assembly with clang (`-fasm-blocks` switch).

Here is an example of successfully compiled asm: https://godbolt.org/z/o57sbq

Not sure if it is a good option for you due clang is not a gcc, but just wanted to mention that. Maybe it can be helpful. Please don't kill me.